# Using pulumi Vs aws cdk for infrastructure provisioning

Tags: devops, aws-cdk, iaas, pulumi

I recently cake to know about pulumi and its capabilities for provisioning infrastructure. I want to draw a comparison between pulumi and aws cdk

Can any tell me what are features that pulumi supports and aws cdk cant? I went through the documentation and different blogs but I am not able to find a good comparison in between them. And why should I use pulumi?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/vs/cloud_template_transpilers/ ?

Comment: I have seen that comparison, which of course will be biased and will miss things they are not doing well.

Comment: Actually I am kind of looking for some neutral comparison that highlights everything for aws cdk vs pulumi .